# Customization of regular expressions in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

I am working on the definition of regular expressions. With the command

```
file=`echo $2 | sed -e "s/\&/\&amp;/g" \
                    -e "s/</\&lt;/g"   \
                    -e "s/>/\&gt;/g"   \
                    -e "s/'/\&apos;/g"`
```

a shell script accesses a file in a file system and then continues editing the file. That works pretty well. However, it can not be used to capture files whose file path contains two spaces in succession.

Is it possible to adapt this command character so that such special cases are included in the file path?

Comment: Quote the variables unless there's a specific reason not to. So `"$2"`, not `$2`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is put the filename in quotes on the command line. For example:

```
$ script.sh arg "file name"
```

The other thing you can do, if the the file name is the last argument the script receives, is to take all of the remaining command line args. E.g.:

```
shift # Shifts off the first argument, so $2 is the first one
file=`echo $* | sed ....`
```

Answer (score 0):

The file name incl. File path I give the command already.
The program "set_attributes" sets with option -w the value 1 to the specified file "path to file"

./set_attributes -u user -p password -w 1 server_2 "path to file"

./set_attributes -u user -p password -w 1 server_2 "/example/**folder 
   1**/filename.jpg

This file gets the program "set_attributes" not handled because there are two blank characters in the file path.